# Combining Multiple Files Into Single Archive (Silverlight/C#)

Tags: c#, io

In Silverlight one does not have access to the entire .NET Library and therefore I am considering the best way to get the functionality I would have courtesy of System.IO.Packaging.

I have multiple text files and I want to combine them into a single archive. Compression is not important but could wind up being valuable.

By instinct I would select an obscure characters as  BOF/EOF tokens and then use a single stream to generate the multiple files, marking off BOF/EOF as a single file. I'd probably come up with a format to retrieve the original file name after the BOF as well.

But before I operate on a poor man's instinctive approach, is there a canonical approach to this? Or anyone who has done this before with some words of advice based on experience?

Answer (score 0):

[SharpZipLib](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=SharpZipLib_MainPage&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) works on the compact framework, there is no reason it won't work in SilverLight.

As for licensing (From their page):

> "In plain English this means you can
>   use this library in commercial
>   closed-source applications."